# Magento search results page giving a server 500 error

Tags: php, magento

I have a test site up for a client using Magento 1.9 community edition.
With a range of products imported I have found this issue:
When I use the product search and search for a range, whenever I click on  asearch result, instead of going to the product page, I get a 500 internal server error.
If I locate the same product by going through the category the product loads perfectly.
Even odder, is after I have opened the product via the category page, the search function WILL load the product page, at least for the very next search.
I'm guessing this is some kind of cache issue but I've rebuilt all of the indexes, cleared the cache and increased the memory limit to 512mb without anything changing. The server is running PHP 5.4.3.

Any advice?

Comment: Check your server's error log files to get a more specific error message.

Comment: 500 errors - always go for the HTTP server error log. It provides pointers for starting your diagnosis. Aside from 503.